# Get the index when combine whereIn with update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
    Asset_component::whereIn('id', $request->input('id'))->update(array(
        'asset_status_id' => Asset_status::whereName('Waiting for transfer')->first()->id,
        'technician_id' => $request->input('technician'),
        'lab_id' => Asset_component::find($index)->asset->lab->id,
        'office_id' => Asset_component::find($index)->asset->office->id,
        'require_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->input('require_date')),
        'comment' => $request->input('comment'),
        'warehouse_id' => null
    ));
```

I need your help to get the $index which is the id index of the loop on update function, any method that can retrieve that ? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Why are you using **whereIn**. i think you should use **where**. Or you can even use **find**

Comment: because the $request->input('id') is an array so i should use where in